# saved items an images disappear

Tags: javascript, performance, savechanges

I am new to developing and I am currently experiencing an issue.I have a membership based website but I keep having the same problems every so often, when a user signs up and writes a bio in his/her profile and saves it, then previews the profile the written bio is no where to be seen it's as if it just gets deleted as soon as you save it. Also I've noticed members trying to upload images to their profile but the same happens again (I can see their uploaded images in the media library).

Can this be anything to do with cache plugins? (I've tried 3 different plugins altogether but the same results).

Comment: It could be? But without an [mcve] _in your question_, it's hard to even know.

Comment: Well someone signed up today, now I don't know if he's attempted to write  bio for sure but what appears in the back end are his images that he's tried to upload to his profile but don't appear.

Comment: I also applied Let's Encrypt which maybe something to do with http/https?

Comment: Ok, but we still can't help you, as we don't know anything about your problem.

Comment: Here's a link to their profile http://www.localgrafters.com/author/rmplastering/ like I said I can see the images he's uploaded in the back end so he's definitely tried to upload

Comment: It may be the total cache plugin I'm using or the Let's Encrypt possibly